# Core Data (Mac) How to implement auto increment on an ID field

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, auto-increment

I was wondering if anyone can point me in the direction of how to set up auto increment on an attribute in a coredata entity. I know the indexed check box just makes the field indexed for searching and lookup speeds.

I also know that I will have to do this in code, but I'm not sure on how to get the last/highest ID to set the new objects ID. I found how to do this years ago but can't find it again.

I have a very limited knowledge of Objective-C and even more so of coredata. Also if someone could suggest how to make sure that a field is unique, such as the name field as well that would be great.

My code is [here](https://files.me.com/ashley.hughes/hjsrcb) if you want to have a look at what I have done so far. The project is a basic database that contains parts and there locations and also tools. It's only partly finished, basically a small database for my person electronics kit. I'm sure there are apps that will do this but its always better when you make it your self

Comment: What I was thinking, I have a class for entity so say Location if when the new button is clicked my code gets the highest id out of the location table and places that value in the id field on the table.

Comment: What do you need an auto-incrementing id field for? It's generally unnecessary in CoreData. If you need a unique identifier, use the `objectID` property. If you need a relationship, set it up in CoreData explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what the id does in your app, but my first observation is that all the entities in your data model have both a name and an id, so they should probably have an abstract super-entity to contain name and id. Other than that, you can retrieve the max id in a set like this:

```
Category *cat = /* get a category  */;
NSSet *parts = cat.parts;
NSNumber *maxID = [parts valueForKeyPath:@"@max.id"];
```

for the id's of a category you could perform a fetch request for all the categories and then use this technique on the array that is returned. I don't know if you want to keep the id's of each model object unique or you want id's to start with 0 for the first object added to each entity.

To make sure a field is unique you can use managed object validation. this is described in the Core Data Programming Guide and in more detail in the Model Object Implementation Guide. Making sure that a name is unique would require you to test it against all the names in a validateName:error: method. making an abstract super entity will make this a lot easier. To do it you get all the names of objects in the abstract super entity and test them against the value to be validated.

Edit: If you use the abstract super entity then you should get the max id of the objects in the abstract super entity if you want them to be unique. Also as someone else pointed out the objectID of a managed object is a unique identifier for it that will always be the same, but looking at the app I don't think that's really what you want, because they will be computer numbers rather than the friendlier results of incrementing the highest known id when a new object is created. Another thing you should set the objet id in awakeFromInsert so that it is only called when the object is created.

Comment: The ID field is the number that I am going to use on the part bins in real life thats why I would like it to be unique and be the next number in the set. I will do as you said and fetch all the categories and find the biggest in the set. I am sure there is something like max() that i can use in the query. I will read up on fetch requests

Comment: Using a fetch request you can get the highest id using a sort descriptor, then calling lastObject on the results array.

Comment: One question, if I use the - (void) awakeFromInsert method I'm getting two of everything in the table. The only way to stop this is to comment out the whole method. Do you know why I have put a break point in the method only gets called once when press the new button.

Comment: when you call insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:, a blank managed object is created and then awakeFromInsert: is called. I don't know why it would insert it twice, unless you are creating a new managed object in awakeFromInsert. I don't know much about NSArrayController's since I'm an iOS developer, but you may need to set the entityName. Looking at the app kit a little more it may be better to set the id in your add method rather than in awakeFromInsert. Also I'm not sure where you are setting what should be in the array controllers.

Comment: the app doesn't add the stored objects into arranged objects when the app starts, and the managed object context is never saved, so anything that you do disappears after you close it. More importantly though, when you add a new component they look like this: ToolBox[15300:a0f] inserted: <Part: 0x100193210> (entity: Part; id: 0x10017aa00 ; data: {
    Current = 1;
    Name = nil;
    Note = nil;
    Picture = nil;
    Quanity = 0;
    category = nil;
    id = 0;
    location = nil;
    specifications =     (
    );
}) notice that there is no category.

Comment: I will add my newest version of the program, nothing is saved until I use file save/save as and file open when i rerun the program.

Comment: https://files.me.com/ashley.hughes/tf5xgg theres the link I don't have enough rep to add another link on the main post

Comment: I worked out that if i turn off the prepares content on the array controller hold my categories I don't get double in the tableview anymore. But now it doesn't show the values that are stored in the save file, but if i do a fetch i can see them. I was thinking in the awake from nib method i could load them. How do i tell the table view/array controller to display the stored values? I am getting close to fixing this.

Comment: I have implemented the auto increment feature now. Still not sure on how to update the table view to display already stored values my code wont fit. But I fetch all the categories sort by their id grab the last object in the array fetch the number, with some ugly code I add one to the last id(NSNumber) and set the new objects ID.

Comment: And I have fixed the problem, I had the NSTableView in the viewController class, but didn't bind the delegate to files owner only the datasource.

Comment: if your still having trouble or you want to see the proper implementation of a similar app check out the departments and employees example http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/DepartmentAndEmployees/DepartmentAndEmployees.zip

Comment: the reason for using an implementation like the departments and employees example is that the relationships between objects isn't being set when you create new rows in the table view. Plus it has auto increment.

Answer (score 1):

this is how apple implemented autoincrement:

```
 - (void) awakeFromInsert
     {
    [super awakeFromInsert];
    static int tempID = 0;
    [self setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:++tempID] forKey:@"id"];
}
```

Comment: DONT USE THIS! The original Apple sample code includes a note that the snippet above is only for illustration purposes, and should not be used in production code. It will reset the auto-increment value to 0 every time you launch the app.

Comment: but then again, having an extra dispatch_once to actually fetch the max "id" for the current entity could work; as long as all inserts are  certain to not be concurrent