# NSManagedObject identification number

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Ok, it seems like I'm asking a noob question (maybe I am and I have just been overlooking important details), but I am looking for a "distinguishing" number/attribute about a generic NSManagedObject that I could use as an ID number (I cannot use the name b/c I want to allow the user to create entities with the same names). If this is not existent please explain how I would recreate this. I understand that I could just add an attribute for this and increment a static variable (ex: currentId) but if I do then I have to consider an entity being deleted then how do I logically place the next inserted entity at that index and then return to the last index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Data does not have the notion of an auto-incremented ID field, keep in mind Core Data is an object graph, not a database. It just happens that a datastore could be backed by a database system, a perfect example is SqlLite.

NSManagedObjectId is kind of like a URL with a GUID to be unique. If you want some sort of auto-incremented id you will have to handle this on your own, there are obviously many different ways you might go about this. You could have a separate entity that stores the last id assigned and read it every time you create a new record, increment the value, use that as your new ID and increment the stored value. This would solve your delete problem if you don't want an ID to be re-used. There are obvious concurrency issues here that you may need to solve. Another approach could be to store the ID in a file on the file system, or in NSUserDefaults, just be sure to take account for concurrency and do not accidentally assign the same ID twice.

Answer (score 0):

There is an objectID method for NSManagedObjects, although I do not believe that they are created in any kind of order.

Personally I would just use and ID attribute. What I don't understand is why deleting would cause any problems. The ID would just sit behind the scenes, there wouldn't be any real reason to show it to the user, right?

Comment: Correct, this is viable and the user never sees them, But I am looking into the primitive value limitations and if the user adds more than an (say for instance) int values max value of entities (which is more than likely to happen in my program) then errors begin occurring.

Comment: My next question then is what is the purpose of the id? What do you want it to accomplish for you that the objectID method doesn't?

Comment: To potentially sync the Core Data scheme to an online DB.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you could use a NSNumber identification row on your entities and then simply keep track of how many objects you have (either by keeping a var or fetching the max value from your storage).

Here I found a few examples that might help you achieve your goal.

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731503/)